# Calling a method with a List Atrribute in Java

Tags: java, string, list, methods, bluej

I am currently looking to call a method that gets me a scrabble score of multiple words and will return the word with the highest score. I have been able to make the method that gets me the score of the words, the next part is to be able to call a method with multiple words and it will return the word with the highest score.

```
public String highestScoringWord(List<String> words) {
    // TODO: find the word with the highest score
    int highestScore = 0;
    String HighScoreWord = "";
    for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++){
        int currentScore = scoreForWord(words.get(i));
        if(currentScore>highestScore){
            HighScoreWord = words.get(i);
        };
    };

    return HighScoreWord;
}
```

I am using blueJ, how will I be able to use it's interface or codePad to call this method with a list of words.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming `yourCodePad` is the object, `String highScore = yourCodePad.highestScoringWord(yourList);`?

Comment: @GBlodgett Will I be able to put the values inside the brackets? ....highestScoreingWord("Hello","One","Dog");

Comment: Yes. Use `highestScoreingWord(Arrays.asList("Hello", "One", "Dog"))`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make the `List<String>` from your words because the method `String highestScoringWord(List<String> words)` only take the `List<String>` as input parameter. In your case now you are able to make `List<String>` from multiple String objects.

```
List<String> words= Arrays.AsList("Word1","Word2","Word3","Word4");
```

Now Pass this list to already defined function `highestScoringWord`.

```
String highestScore=highestScoringWord(words);
```

You'll get your desired result.

Comment: Please  add some explanation as well along with this code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or newer, you can use streams to get the "max" of the score list you are about to create:

```java
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat", "Bird");
int highest = words.stream()
        .map(this::scoreForWord)
        .max(Integer::compareTo)
        .orElse(0);
```

What this code does:

- `words.stream()` - Initialises a stream using the word list.
- `.map(this::scoreForWord)` - Transforms each string to `int` using the logic of `int scoreForWord(String)` function. The method is referred as `this` because I assumed that it is an instance method. If ever the method is `static` you must use the class name to refer the function: `ScrabbleScorer::scoreForWord`
- `.max(Integer::compareTo)` - Gets the maximum value of the `Integer` stream created from the previous operation. The logic will be the default integer comparator (that is the `Integer::compareTo`)
- `.orElse(0)` - Since the `.max()` operation returns an `Optional<Integer>` when the given list in the very beginning is empty - we shall handle the empty return scenario. We used the value `0` to assume such case.